# Change the position of widget within a grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid-layout, cells

What I need to know is if there is a way to put a widget into a different grid cell after already gridding it. The reason I need to do this is because I am making a tkinter program in python with multiple stacked frames, and I made a class that inherits from the `Frame` class called `ParentFrame`. All other frames in the program inherit from `ParentFrame`. Part of its function is to automatically grid all slave frames within it.

Here's where the problem comes in. I want one single slave frame to be positioned differently, but it has already been positioned by `ParentFrame` in the grid. Is it possible to reconfigure the slave frame's location after already being in the grid?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `grid_forget()`?

Comment: I was going to use `grid_forget()` as a last resort, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner, 1-function way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to put it in a different grid cell. Just call `grid` again with different parameters. There is no need to remove it first.

```
...
my_button.grid(row=0, column=1, ...)
...
my_button.grid(row=1, column=3, ...)
...
```

Comment: Does this remove the widget from the original position?

Comment: @PlatypusVenom: yes, it does. A widget can only be in one place.